# Pattern for creating an instance of a class from a UI form

Tags: python, ui

The following is a contrived example of a potential code smell
that I've repeatedly encountered when implementing a GUI with which instances of a class created by letting the user fill out a form. The question is if the pattern I use is correct, or if there is a better way.

The app's core logic contains a class `Data` that is initialized with
a `Dict` (among other things):

```py
class Data:
    def __init__(self, stuff: Dict, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        self.stuff = stuff
        # ...
```

The attribute `self.things` is read-only. Note that `__init__` has other arguments,
which are used to set other attributes of `Data`.

The main use-case is that `raw` is read from a `.json` file:

```py
with open(path, 'r') as f:
    raw = f.read()
stuff = json.loads(raw)
data = Data(stuff, ...)
```

Instances of `Data` may be created using a UI form,
in which the user enters a filesystem path (from which `raw` is read)
and the other parameters of `__init__`.
The instances should also be managed by the app's UI; when the app is closed, the
`Data` instances should be serialized, saved, and later loaded again.
Out of the potentially very large database of `Data` objects,
only very few are required at the same time.

To prevent massive data duplication (let's say the file at `path` is
very large, and potentially used by many `Data` objects) and to allow
editing the `Data` instances by changing the path that the `raw`
parameter is read from, the file path should be saved, *not* the data
itself.

This means that the `Data` instances themselves cannot be serialized.
Instead, I've opted to use an intermediate class

```py
class DataInfo:
    def __init__(self, path: str, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        self.path = path
        # Store everything in attributes...

    def deploy(self) -> Data:
        with open(path, 'r') as f:
            raw = f.read()
        stuff = json.loads(raw)
        data = Data(stuff, ...)
        return data
```

The instances of this class are used to store the initialization args
for `Data`, and on `DataInfo` instances are serialized/loaded.
Once the `Data` object is actually required (remember that
only very few of the instances are required at each moment), it is
constructed by calling `deploy`.

Maybe I'm misjudging this, but this pattern feels slightly awkward. Is this (roughly) the correct pattern for this situation? Does it have a name? Or are there more readable/less intrusive or well-known patterns that solve this problem (by "well-known" I mean something that for, for instance, be suggested in the official Qt documentation)?

Comment: @DocBrown My bad... Fixed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general strategy (to load the actual data of a `Data` object only on-demand) seems to be fine. And yes, this has indeed a common name, it is called [**Lazy Loading**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading).

The way you implemented will surely work. Let me suggest a different approach, though.

My first thought when I saw this design was

- why can a `Data` object not simply load it's data on-demand **"behind the scenes"**, automatically, when the data is needed first?

Instead of introducing another class `DataInfo` which the caller must know and deal with, a `Data` object might be constructed with a path parameter, and load the related file immediately when the first accessor method is called.

That would abstract the lazy loading completely away from the code which uses the `Data` objects, so making the usage a little bit simpler.

There may be reasons why you want to keep `Data` objects separated from the path of their related JSON file. For this case, you may consider to design the solution with a [proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern) class, where `DataProxy` has almost the same public interface as `Data`, holds the path and a reference to a `Data` object which is lazy-loaded when it is required. As a variant of this, one may make `Data` itself the proxy, and give the current `Data` class a different name like `DataContainer`.

IMHO there is not enough context in the question to judge if any of these approaches is really simpler or easier to handle than your current approach. But I am sure you can evaluate by yourself if they will bring you any benefits for your system.